# How Emmet Go to Matching Pair works on header.php file with unclosed divs

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, emmet

Hello i am using VS Code. In emmet i have a problem of go to matching tag in header.php. My header.php has some unclosed div. I think therefore emmet go to matching pair opiton is not working. Is there is any workaround for emmet to work in unclosed tags.

My header.php file code is as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<!-- Mirrored from radixtouch.in/templates/admin/aegis/source/light/index.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Mon, 04 May 2020 09:24:49 GMT -->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
  <title>Aegis - Admin Dashboard Template</title>
  <!-- General CSS Files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/app.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bundles/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bundles/weather-icon/css/weather-icons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bundles/weather-icon/css/weather-icons-wind.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bundles/summernote/summernote-bs4.css">
  <!-- Template CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/components.css">
  <!-- Custom style CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/custom.css">
  <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/favicon.ico' />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="main-wrapper main-wrapper-1">
      <div class="navbar-bg"></div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg main-navbar">
        <div class="form-inline mr-auto">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-3">
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="sidebar" class="nav-link nav-link-lg
                                    collapse-btn"> <i data-feather="align-justify"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-lg fullscreen-btn">
                <i data-feather="maximize"></i>
              </a></li>
            <li>
              <form class="form-inline mr-auto">
                <div class="search-element">
                  <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" data-width="200">
                  <button class="btn" type="submit">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-list-toggle"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
              class="nav-link nav-link-lg message-toggle"><i data-feather="mail"></i>
              <span class="badge headerBadge1">
                6 </span> </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-list dropdown-menu-right pullDown">
              <div class="dropdown-header">
                Messages
                <div class="float-right">
                  <a href="#">Mark All As Read</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown-list-content dropdown-list-message">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span class="dropdown-item-avatar
                                            text-white"> <img alt="image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/users/user-1.png" class="rounded-circle">
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> <span class="message-user">John
                      Deo</span>
                    <span class="time messege-text">Please check your mail !!</span>
                    <span class="time">2 Min Ago</span>
                  </span>
                </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span class="dropdown-item-avatar text-white">
                    <img alt="image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/users/user-2.png" class="rounded-circle">
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> <span class="message-user">Sarah
                      Smith</span> <span class="time messege-text">Request for leave
                      application</span>
                    <span class="time">5 Min Ago</span>
                  </span>
                </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span class="dropdown-item-avatar text-white">
                    <img alt="image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/users/user-5.png" class="rounded-circle">
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> <span class="message-user">Jacob
                      Ryan</span> <span class="time messege-text">Your payment invoice is
                      generated.</span> <span class="time">12 Min Ago</span>
                  </span>
                </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span class="dropdown-item-avatar text-white">
                    <img alt="image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/users/user-4.png" class="rounded-circle">
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> <span class="message-user">Lina
                      Smith</span> <span class="time messege-text">hii John, I have upload
                      doc
                      related to task.</span> <span class="time">30
                      Min Ago</span>
                  </span>
                </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span class="dropdown-item-avatar text-white">
                    <img alt="image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/users/user-3.png" class="rounded-circle">
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> <span class="message-user">Jalpa
                      Joshi</span> <span class="time messege-text">Please do as specify.
                      Let me
                      know if you have any query.</span> <span class="time">1
                      Days Ago</span>
                  </span>
                </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span class="dropdown-item-avatar text-white">
                    <img alt="image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/users/user-2.png" class="rounded-circle">
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> <span class="message-user">Sarah
                      Smith</span> <span class="time messege-text">Client Requirements</span>
                    <span class="time">2 Days Ago</span>
                  </span>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown-footer text-center">
                <a href="#">View All <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-list-toggle"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
              class="nav-link notification-toggle nav-link-lg"><i data-feather="bell"></i>
              <span class="badge headerBadge2">
                3 </span> </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-list dropdown-menu-right pullDown">
              <div class="dropdown-header">
                Notifications
                <div class="float-right">
                  <a href="#">Mark All As Read</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown-list-content dropdown-list-icons">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-unread"> <span
                    class="dropdown-item-icon bg-primary text-white"> <i class="fas
                                                fa-code"></i>
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> Template update is
                    available now! <span class="time">2 Min
                      Ago</span>
                  </span>
                </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span class="dropdown-item-icon bg-info text-white"> <i class="far
                                                fa-user"></i>
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> <b>You</b> and <b>Dedik
                      Sugiharto</b> are now friends <span class="time">10 Hours
                      Ago</span>
                  </span>
                </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span class="dropdown-item-icon bg-success text-white"> <i
                      class="fas
                                                fa-check"></i>
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> <b>Kusnaedi</b> has
                    moved task <b>Fix bug header</b> to <b>Done</b> <span class="time">12
                      Hours
                      Ago</span>
                  </span>
                </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span class="dropdown-item-icon bg-danger text-white"> <i
                      class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> Low disk space. Let's
                    clean it! <span class="time">17 Hours Ago</span>
                  </span>
                </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> <span class="dropdown-item-icon bg-info text-white"> <i class="fas
                                                fa-bell"></i>
                  </span> <span class="dropdown-item-desc"> Welcome to Aegis
                    template! <span class="time">Yesterday</span>
                  </span>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown-footer text-center">
                <a href="#">View All <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-link-lg nav-link-user"> <img alt="image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/user.png"
                class="user-img-radious-style"> <span class="d-sm-none d-lg-inline-block"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right pullDown">
              <div class="dropdown-title">Hello Sarah Smith</div>
              <a href="profile.html" class="dropdown-item has-icon"> <i class="far
                                        fa-user"></i> Profile
              </a> <a href="timeline.html" class="dropdown-item has-icon"> <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>
                Activities
              </a> <a href="#" class="dropdown-item has-icon"> <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                Settings
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a href="auth-login.html" class="dropdown-item has-icon text-danger"> <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
                Logout
              </a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

As you see there are two unclosed div and body and html tag. It it closed in footer file.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to close the div tag manually, and I recommend writing standard HTML code

Comment: thanks for your feedback but manually approach i already known.